# "A planta exige pouca água" significa que muita água é prejudicial ou meramente desnecessária?

Tags: significado, ambiguidades

Lembro-me de uma discussão deste tipo há uns anos, em que ambas as interpretações foram defendidas com unhas e dentes. A expressão da contenda poderá ter sido **exige pouco trabalho** ou **exige pouca experiência**, ou coisa assim.

A construção **exige pouco** admite as duas interpretações, **tem que ser pouco** e **não é necessário muito**? Ou só uma está correta? É usada com ambos os significados? Depende do contexto? E para não estarmos a discutir isto às pinguinhas, faço a mesma pergunta acerca de **precisa de pouco** e **requer pouco**.

Comment: (`a construção XPTO o admite as duas interpre...` - isto tem um "o" a mais.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diria que, tecnicamente, ambas as  interpretações são possíveis. Isto aplica-se a todas estas frases:

> - A planta **exige** pouca água.
> - A planta **precisa de** pouca água.
> - A planta **necessita de** pouca água.
> - A planta **requer** pouca água.

Mas dito isto, sem mais contexto, eu favoreceria muito a interpretação "não precisa de muita água" em detrimento de "não lhe pode ser dada muita água"/"precisa que se lhe seja dada pouca água", analogamente a:

> Tem pouco que se lhe diga (= não tem muito que se lhe diga).

Pesquisando no CETEMPúblico, quer com `[lema="precisar|necessitar"] "de" ("pouco"|"pouca"|"poucos"|"poucas")`, quer com `[lema="exigir|requerer"] ("pouco"|"pouca"|"poucos"|"poucas")`, a não ser que algo me tenha escapado, **todos** os (20+23) resultados significavam "não ser preciso muito".

A razão por que esta interpretação é favorecida deve dever-se a que "precisar", "exigir", etc. têm normalmente uma expectativa de adição; partem de uma ideia de falta, necessidade. Uma "necessidade de ter menos" é possível, mas geralmente precisa de ser indicada mais explicitamente.

(Por alguma razão `[lema="pouco"]` inclui resultados com `menos`; olhei um pouco para esses resultados e com "precisa de menos" já tínhamos as duas interpretações: "a empresa precisa de menos trabalhadores; tem de despedir"; "o novo método precisa de menos recursos que o anterior")

Answer (score 4):

**Sem nenhuma informação adicional, significa exatamente isso: que não se deve, ou não é necessário regá-la com a mesma frequência ou intensidade que as outras plantas.**

**A frase é ambígua porque não discerne entre "não se deve" e "não é necessário".**  Contudo, se eu lesse tal instrução, e soubesse tratar-se de uma tradução do Inglês, eu tenderia a achar que foi mal traduzida e que o significado "não é necessário" seria a mensagem pretendida. ***De qualquer forma, fosse qual fosse a intenção de quem escreveu, é melhor regá-la pouco e não haverá erro.***

Já "a planta precisa de pouca água" e "a planta requer pouca água" tendem mais para "não é necessário" embora algumas pessoas possam achá-las ambíguas, principalmente a segunda forma. Caso o objetivo fosse transmitir a ideia de "deve ser regada com menos água que as outras plantas", melhor seria dizer "pouca água é a regra para esta planta" ou "regue com pouca água pois água em quantidades normais será prejudicial à planta".  Geralmente esse tipo de informação também faz alusão à frequência - duas vezes por semana, diáriamente, etc.